# How to tell mypy an object is always Falsy

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Consider this example, where we have a custom "implicit bool" class `FalsyType`.

```
import typing as t


class FalsyType:
    def __bool__(self) -> t.Literal[False]:
        return False


Falsy = FalsyType()

a: t.Union[FalsyType, str]
a = Falsy

mylist: t.List[str] = []
if a:
    mylist.append(a)

a = "Hello"
if a:
    mylist.append(a)
```

mypy (version=0.910 & python==3.8.8) gives the following error:

```
16:19: error: Argument 1 to "append" of "list" has incompatible type "FalsyType"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
        mylist.append(a)
```

How to make mypy understand that `a` is Falsy and cannot be added to mylist after the condition?

Using isinstance check you can work around this issue, however, this is easy to forget or misunderstand when you have various Falsy classes like this.

```
if not isinstance(a, FalsyType):
   mylist.append(a)
```

Related:

- [the type of a variable that can be implicitly checked for "zeroness" or "emptiness"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654434/the-type-of-a-variable-that-can-be-implicitly-checked-for-zeroness-or-emptine)
- https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/10557

EDIT: Clarify that `a` can be a str

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's any point to this. If you've got dead code with static type errors, why not just remove the dead code instead of trying to get mypy to ignore the errors?

Comment: I might have missed that in the example, but `a` can sometimes be a string as well. Therefore, it's not dead code.

Comment: There might be a mypy bug here. If I merge the `a` annotation and assignment, mypy reports no errors. I still get no errors if I then randomly decide whether `a` should be `Falsy` or `'asdf'`: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=acc25c8716d1ab4b3e0b8c1bf0f8177b

Comment: I think mypy reports an error if it's sure that `a` is not a `str`. With the unconditional assignment after the annotation, mypy recognizes that the effective type of `a` is more specific than the declared type. This should only be an issue for dead code.

Comment: Agree, I think the issue is that MyPy is disregarding your initial type annotation because it realises that it can be more specific in its type inference than you yourself were. MyPy reports that the revealed type of `a` is `FalsyType`, not `Union[str, FalsyType]`

Comment: Indeed that is exactly the case. MyPy reports that the revealed type as FalsyType, not Union[str, FalsyType]. Therefore, it seems that the issue we're having is actually because the inferred type is more specific. I'm trying to find out why that is happening in our internal codebase, likely a mistake in our type hints somewhere. To give some context, we use a serialization library like pydantic to parse data into dataclasses, so there is a bit of typing magic there.